# Issue with creating array inside array in angular 8 model

Tags: javascript, angular, multidimensional-array, angular8

I am trying to create a model named "reportVersion"

This contains an array (ReportCategory) that contains objects collection and two variables one is numeric and another is a string.

I am creating this model just to pass to an API, as a parameter body.

Since I have not created a model in the submission form, in the same format as like needs to be passed as a parameter to an API. I need to do fetch values from form Model and push it to reportVersion. Further, I will pass reportVersion to the API as a parameter to call the api.

Currently, I facing issues while building reportVersion.
I have put the code below in stackblitz.

I don't understand why console.log(model) is not printing to console.
Please help.

```
  this.reportCategory.push({ categoryName: 'demo1', weightage: 10 });

    this.reportCategory.push({ categoryName: 'demo2', weightage: 20 });

    this.reportCategory.push({ categoryName: 'demo3', weightage: 30 });

    this.reportCategory.forEach((element) => {
      this.reportVersion['categories'].push({
        categoryName: element.categoryName,
        weightage: element.weightage,
      });
    });
    console.log('this is final output');
    console.log(this.reportCategory);
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vu99yk?file=src/app/hello.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to initialize the **reportCategory** before using methods on it (like push).

```
this.reportCategory = []; // Added this line
this.reportCategory.push({ categoryName: 'demo1', weightage: 10 });
this.reportCategory.push({ categoryName: 'demo2', weightage: 20 });
this.reportCategory.push({ categoryName: 'demo3', weightage: 30 });
```

It worked in the StackBlitz in my side :)

// Dylan

Comment: Super thanks for the help, please tell me my approach is correct, is the right way of building a model which needs to be passed to an API?

Comment: i am concerned only because there are array inside an array

Comment: is there any better way of doing this ?

Comment: I don't know if I understand your question, but if I refer on what there is in the StackBlitz, nothing made me cry!
It is totally acceptable for a model to have a field which is an Array. It is a classic 1-n relationship.